# setting Sklearn's CountVectorizer's vocabulary to a dict of phrases

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

Hello I've been playing around with using text analysis using scikit-learn and I had the idea of using the CountVectorizer to detect whether a document contains set of keywords and phrases.

I know that we can do this:

```
words = ['cat', 'dog', 'walking']
example = ['I was walking my dog and cat in the park']
vect = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=words)
dtm = vect.fit_transform(example)
>>> pd.DataFrame(dtm.toarray(), columns=vect.get_feature_names())
```

...

```
   cat  dog  walking
    1    1        1
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to tweak things so that I can use word phrases instead of just individual words

From the example above:

```
phrases = ['cat in the park', 'walking my dog']
example = ['I was walking my dog and cat in the park']
vect = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=phrases)
dtm = vect.fit_transform(example)
>>> pd.DataFrame(dtm.toarray(), columns=vect.get_feature_names()) 
... 

       cat in the park   walking my dog
            1                   1
```

Right now the code using the phrases just outputs

```
cat in the park   walking my dog
     0                   0
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [104]: lens = [len(x.split()) for x in phrases]

In [105]: mn, mx = min(lens), max(lens)

In [106]: vect = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=phrases, ngram_range=(mn, mx))

In [107]: dtm = vect.fit_transform(example)

In [108]: pd.DataFrame(dtm.toarray(), columns=vect.get_feature_names())
Out[108]:
   cat in the park  walking my dog
0                1               1

In [109]: print(mn, mx)
3 4
```

Comment: Works perfectly for the example above, but when I use the method in the function I'm building while the vocabulary get's set up it's not detecting the phrase in the document. I'll try troubleshooting on my own for a bit to see what's going on.

Comment: got it, I accepted the answer thank you again for your help!

Comment: @cgclip, did you figured out how to do it? I'm facing this same problem, where some phrases share the same word, I don't want the vectorizer to match individual words but complete phrases.